# Two Questions: 1.) How to push object to array outside of scope? 2.) Is there a better way to invoke this resolved promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create an array that holds all of my objects to be able to `JSON.stringify()` and pass to my frontend. However, the array that is outside the scope of `.then()` is not being updated when I invoke `array.push({ obj })`, which screams scoping issue.

How can I update my array?
Also, is there a better way to handle my promise objects? The reason behind it is I needed some data from my initial promise that would be passed to my secondary promise. However, I have a feeling that it can be written in a better way.

Thank you for your time.

edit: A word

```
app.get('/route-submission', (req,res) => {

    const station = req.query.station;
    const destination = req.query.destination;

    var routesAndEvents = [];


    /**
     * Goal is to pass departures, fares, and events in one JSON object 
     */
    getStationInfo(station, destination).then( apiResponse => {

        const { routes, fare, longLat } = apiResponse;
        let departures = manageRoutes( routes, destination );
        let fares = manageFares( fare );
        let longLatData = manageLongLat ( longLat );

        routesAndEvents.push({
            departures: departures,
            fare: fares
        })

        getEventInfo( longLatData ).then( apiResponse => {
            let eventData = apiResponse.data.events ;
            let managedEvents = manageEvents( eventData );
            console.log( routesAndEvents );
        })
    })

    res.send ( JSON.stringify(routesAndEvents) );
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking the `res.send` outside the `then` callback, that line can be invoked before your promise is completed. By that time, the array may not have updated yet. So move your `res.send` into the second `then` as follows.

```
getStationInfo(station, destination).then( apiResponse => {

    const { routes, fare, longLat } = apiResponse;
    let departures = manageRoutes( routes, destination );
    let fares = manageFares( fare );
    let longLatData = manageLongLat ( longLat );

    routesAndEvents.push({
        departures: departures,
        fare: fares
    })

    getEventInfo( longLatData ).then( apiResponse => {
        let eventData = apiResponse.data.events ;
        let managedEvents = manageEvents( eventData );
        console.log( routesAndEvents );
        res.send ( JSON.stringify(routesAndEvents) );
    })
})
```

And see the comment below by @wrobbinz on how you can avoid nesting promises.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. As for the second question, is there a better way to write the `.then` callback instead of having one inside the other? i.e. pass `longLatData` to `getEventInfo` outside of `getStationInfo`?

Comment: You can avoid nesting the promises by chaining them. Return a value from within the `.then()` and the return value will be a promise. Since the return value is a promise, it ALSO has a `.then()` property, that you can use. See here for code example. https://jsfiddle.net/mqz6w87g/